# WP job manager change search results order

Tags: php, wordpress

at the minute the search results are sorted by alphabetic order.
I need them to be sorted by closest to the search locations.
I'm using WP job manager and the search is provided by google map api

function get_job_listings( $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb, $job_manager_keyword;

```
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
    'search_location'   => '',
    'search_keywords'   => '',
    'search_categories' => array(),
    'job_types'         => array(),
    'post_status'       => array(),
    'offset'            => 0,
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'featured'          => null,
    'filled'            => null,
    'fields'            => 'all'
) );

if ( $args['posts_per_page'] < 0 ) {
    $query_args['no_found_rows'] = true;
}

if ( ! empty( $args['search_location'] ) ) {
    $location_meta_keys = array( 'geolocation_formatted_address', '_job_location', 'geolocation_state_long' );
    $location_search    = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
    foreach ( $location_meta_keys as $meta_key ) {
        $location_search[] = array(
            'key'     => $meta_key,
            'value'   => $args['search_location'],
            'compare' => 'like'
        );
    }
    $query_args['meta_query'][] = $location_search;
}

if ( ! is_null( $args['featured'] ) ) {
    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'     => '_featured',
        'value'   => '1',
        'compare' => $args['featured'] ? '=' : '!='
    );
}

if ( ! is_null( $args['filled'] ) || 1 === absint( get_option( 'job_manager_hide_filled_positions' ) ) ) {
    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'     => '_filled',
        'value'   => '1',
        'compare' => $args['filled'] ? '=' : '!='
    );
}

if ( ! empty( $args['job_types'] ) ) {
    $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $args['job_types']
    );
}

if ( ! empty( $args['search_categories'] ) ) {
    $field    = is_numeric( $args['search_categories'][0] ) ? 'term_id' : 'slug';
    $operator = 'all' === get_option( 'job_manager_category_filter_type', 'all' ) && sizeof( $args['search_categories'] ) > 1 ? 'AND' : 'IN';
    $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'job_listing_category',
        'field'            => $field,
        'terms'            => array_values( $args['search_categories'] ),
        'include_children' => $operator !== 'AND' ,
        'operator'         => $operator
    );
}
```

If you need any more code please let me know.